# C#: Populating combobox from stored procedure only displays first item

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am trying to populate a combobox at initialization by executing a stored procedure. When I run the procedure on my DB, there are 3 rows that come out:

[image]

But once I execute the procedure in my code:

```
public partial class AddInstitutionStart : Window
    {
        public AddInstitutionStart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ComboBoxInstitutionCategory.Items.Add(FillCombo.fillInstCategory());
        }
    }

    public static class FillCombo
    {
        public static string fillInstCategory()
        {
            string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection Connect = null;
            SqlCommand Command;
            using (Connect = new SqlConnection(connstr))
            {
                Connect.Open();
                using (Command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[spMetadataTb_GetCategory]", Connect))
                {
                    Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlDataReader dr = Command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        string categoryInst = dr.GetString(0);
                        return categoryInst;
                    }
                }

                Command.Dispose();
                Connect.Close();
                return "-2";
            }
        }
    }
```

Only the first row is displayed:

[image]

I have used the same logic to fill another combobox (not at initialization) and it works perfectly and displays multiple item. Any idea on what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Because you are returning from your loop when you have read the first instance...`return categoryInst;` I think you need to return a list, add to it in the loop and return at the end...Edit....and if there is an `AddRange()` method, use it instead of `.Add()`

Comment: You have implemented `using` code blocks. There is no need to use `Close` or `Dispose`.  Just remove the local variables declaration "SqlConnection Connect = null;" and "SqlCommand Command;" and do this instead: `using (var Connect = new SqlConnection(connstr))' and `using (var Command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[spMeta...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tons of possible solutions for this, but please **forget the *static*!**

### 1st:

return a List from the other answer, use it like this:

```
public partial class AddInstitutionStart : Window
{
    public AddInstitutionStart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach(string cat in new FillCombo().fillInstCategory())
            ComboBoxInstitutionCategory.Items.Add(cat);
    }
}
```

or, if `AddRange` exists:

```
public partial class AddInstitutionStart : Window
{
    public AddInstitutionStart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ComboBoxInstitutionCategory.Items.AddRange(new FillCombo().fillInstCategory());
    }
}
```

This solution 1st fills the list in `fillInstCategory()`, then fills your *combobox* via foreach or addrange.

### 2nd:

make it to an enumerable function (use it same as above):

Only 2 change in your code, 1st:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetInstCategory()
{
    ...
}
```

then extend the *return* word with *yield*:

```
        while (dr.Read())
            yield return dr.GetString(0);
```

this fills the *combobox* right after each data is read (not once, when all data is read as with solution 1), because ***yield*** causes jumping back and forth between your `Items.Add` and `While(dr.Read())` code parts.

### 3rd:

inject a method (or lambda expression):

Only 2 change in your code, 1st:

```
public void GetInstCategory(Action<string> Injection)
{
    ...
}
```

then:

```
        while (dr.Read())
            Injection(dr.GetString(0));
```

Use it like:

```
public partial class AddInstitutionStart : Window
{
    public AddInstitutionStart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        new FillCombo().fillInstCategory(ComboBoxInstitutionCategory.Items.Add)) //note there is no "(" and ")" after Add, so the addition doesnt happen, just the function was passed to "fillInstCategory" to use it whenever necessary.
    }
}
```

This fills the same way your combobox as solution 2: Reads 1 data, then Adds 1 to combobox, then reads again...

I hope you learn something from this.

Comment: Thank You. I have used the first option

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...only dispose of your reader also.

```
public static List<string> fillInstCategory()
{
    string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection Connect = null;
    SqlCommand Command;
    List<string> categories = new List<string>();
    using (Connect = new SqlConnection(connstr))
    {
        Connect.Open();
        using (Command = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[spMetadataTb_GetCategory]", Connect))
        {
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader dr = Command.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string categoryInst = dr.GetString(0);
                categories.Add(categoryInst);
            }
        }

        Command.Dispose();
        Connect.Close();
        return categories;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Simon. This method is not working. It is not giving the 3 rows I expect but instead just one: (collection)